# Slim 4, why the ajax call succeed but it gives 404 error on cPanel?

Tags: php, api, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, slim

so, it works perfectly on my local, but when deployed on cPanel got that error,
the answer is perfect.. but with 404 status...
and in local it comes with the 200 status as it should

so i assume is a .htaccess thing

this is the .htaccess in the root of my project

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^$ /$1 [L]
   RewriteRule (^[^/]*$) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and this is the one in my_project/public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your project root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

And this in your `public/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```